# Disable traffic map views with HERE JavaScript API

Tags: here-api

HERE Map material comes with different map views and possible overlays like 'Traffic conditions', 'Public transport' and 'Incidents'. I do not want to offer these three views at all. Unfortunately, I was only able to deactivate them by the following code:

```
//disable traffic information
var control = HEREMap.ui.getControl('mapsettings');  
control.getChildren()[1].m[3].setDisabled(true);
control.getChildren()[1].m[2].setDisabled(true);
control.getChildren()[1].m[1].setDisabled(true);
```

However, this leaves me with gray, unclickable options for like 'Traffic conditions', 'Public transport' and 'Incidents'. Is there a way to show them not at all using the JavaScript API?

Thanks in advance, Team DG7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty but it works.  Follow the same approach to remove the hr.

```
$(".H_btn:contains('Traffic conditions')").hide();
$(".H_btn:contains('Public transport')").hide();
$(".H_btn:contains('Show traffic incidents')").hide();
```

alternative without jQuery:

```
control.getChildren()[1].m[3].el.hidden = true; 
control.getChildren()[1].m[2].el.hidden = true; 
control.getChildren()[1].m[1].el.hidden = true;
```

Comment: Why assuming that he wants to use jQuery? You should at least mention that your answer requires it. JavaScript !== jQuery

Comment: control.getChildren()[1].m[3].el.hidden = true;  control.getChildren()[1].m[2].el.hidden = true;  control.getChildren()[1].m[1].el.hidden = true;

Comment: Didn't get to format the code in time but it works without JQuery.

Comment: And why didn't you edit your answer this time? Besides - what happened to `:contains` in your new proposition?

Comment: if I change the answer, the comments won't make any sense.  The contains is no longer required as he is referencing the specific menu items by the nodes.  The object has a el with a property of hidden that can be set to true.

Comment: Thank you, William, for keeping both solutions. Makes things clearer

Answer (score 2):

As of 8/2018, there does not appear to be any option in the API to create the default UI without the traffic views.

I used the following code to clean up the default menu:

```
let mapsettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
let menuEntries = mapsettings.getChildren()[1].getChildren();
menuEntries[0].getElement().style.borderBottom = 'none';
for (let i=1; i<menuEntries.length; i++)
    menuEntries[i].setVisibility(false);
```