# Here Map - hide traffic ui

Tags: here-api

Hi is it possible to hide the traffic section in settings UI from Here map? 
[hide traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNIMo.png)

I do not need any traffic information on the map. 
Is it also possible to change colors from the ui. 
 Thanks Othmar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859871/disable-traffic-map-views-with-here-javascript-api/51729080

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

As of 8/2018, there does not appear to be any option in the API to create the default UI without the traffic views.

Youcan use the following code to clean up the default menu:

```
let mapsettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
let menuEntries = mapsettings.getChildren()[1].getChildren();
menuEntries[0].getElement().style.borderBottom = 'none';
for (let i=1; i<menuEntries.length; i++)
    menuEntries[i].setVisibility(false);
```